# Pseudo-class nesting / SCSS Linter Warning

Tags: css, sass, scss-lint

I'm relatively new to SCSS and try to improve my skills using a linter. I have this little example, where I want to display a submenu only if the parent menu-item is hovered. While this code is working, the linter gives me a "Class should be nested within its parent Pseudo-class".

```css
.menu-item { 
  .submenu {
    display: none;
  }

  &:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='menu-item'>
    <a href=''>
      Menu 1
    </a>
    <ul class='submenu'>
      <li>Submenu 1.1</li>
      <li>Submenu 1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have no idea how the :hover part could be nested into the .submenu part. Can you help?

Comment: My opinion is that linters are someone else's opinion and therefore neither the linter nor this comment matter ;)

Comment: The code seems perfectly ok. Does you SASS code compiling when you are using it?

Comment: The code is working as expected. I'm just wondering if the nesting could be improved.

Comment: If the linter were smart, it should be telling you **not** to do so much nesting. Of course, if it were **really** smart it would be telling you not to use SCSS at all. By the way, could you please edit your question to put the actual question in the title?

Comment: Why would you recommend using no scss at all? Would you use pure CSS instead and why? Don't you miss mixins and variables?

Comment: @torazaburo uh, what?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution and it was so simple, I just had to nest the .submenu into the hover part :(

```css
.menu-item { 
  .submenu {
    display: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    .submenu {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='menu-item'>
    <a href=''>
      Menu 1
    </a>
    <ul class='submenu'>
      <li>Submenu 1.1</li>
      <li>Submenu 1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SASS code will compiled to the below CSS code which is working fine. Just make sure that your SASS code is properly compiling to CSS.

```css
.menu-item .submenu {
  display: none;
}

.menu-item:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='menu-item'>
    <a href=''>
      Menu 1
    </a>
    <ul class='submenu'>
      <li>Submenu 1.1</li>
      <li>Submenu 1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know that it's compiling correct, but I thought that it might be possible to nest the hover part into the .submenu part somehow. But I don't know how to select the parents-parent element which would be needed for doing something like:

Comment: I care less about the compiled css than about the sass file. Because the linter says that it should be nested, I'm trying to find out, how.